# BigQuery streaming - our data is not showing up anymore

Tags: google-bigquery

We're using the BigQuery streaming API, and we have been for some time now. We noticed that about 4:05am UTC (June 18th) BigQuery was no longer reporting any new data being streamed in. We checked all our logs, and everything looks good, and we're even getting back 200's from the `insertAll()` request.

As a test, we created a table, and used the online `insertAll()` 'Test it!' [webpage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll). Again, everything looks good, but the data is not showing up in BigQuery. We know that data might not be visible for a while, but we've never seen it take more than 5 minutes max to be available.

Is there any known issue with BigQuery streaming currently?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Report here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigquery-downtime-notify/O9di3uJPlqU/vsq1DiUI8bQJ. Subscribe to this list for timely announcements. Apologies for the inconveniences!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is under investigation, see:
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=263

More information in this forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-downtime-notify